# what is top.passback() in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm dealing with some old @ss legacy code that was written 3 or 4 developers ago....  Apparently there is some unfinished code and I'm getting errors that passback is not a valid function.

The line in question is: `top.passBack('curCtrl', r + "," + g + "," + b);`

I've done some research and I couldn't find any reference to a javascript function called passBack.  I searched the project and couldn't find any references to custom function called passBack either.

Was passBack used a long time ago and has it been depreciated?  I've seen that .opener comes up when I search for passBack.  I tried the examples in opener but it says that it returns NULL...  This project is a little hokey when it comes to popups and screens.  Everything is done through a component (no separation).

Any ideas?

Comment: How is the variable "top" being instantiated, what kind of object is it?

Comment: @Bodman "top" is a property of the "window" object.

Comment: `passBack()` is not a DOM method.  It's likely that at some point in the past this function was implemented by a previous developer but then removed.  It's probably time to start looking through the revision history of your codebase.

Comment: `top` is a member of `window` which points to the top-most window object (in a nested hierarchy of frames, this is the outermost window)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `top` property of the window object refers to the topmost window in a hierarchy (a parent-child chain).  It's generally used when you've got frames or iframes.

Thus there's probably some global function `passBack` on the parent window, or at least the code expects there to be.

[Here is the MDN page about `window.top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.top).  All browsers I know of support it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess "passBack" sounds like code that controls communication between the main browser window and any popups that it has opened.  With the names of variables "r" "g" "b" as parameters it sounds like it's setting a color somewhere.